# Which data type to use for different configurations

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a 4 different configurations to be used and these configuration values are stored in a property file. The properties for all the configurations are same, but the values are different for each.

Ex:
The property file configurations I am using:

```
####Config1####
conf1.password=admin
conf1.username=admin
conf1.context=123
conf1.name=localhost

####config2####
conf2.username=app
conf2.password=app
conf2.context=com
conf2.name=localhost

####config3####
conf3.username=app
conf3.password=app
conf3.context=com
conf3.name=localhost

####config4####
conf4.username=app
conf4.password=app
conf4.context=com
conf4.name=localhost
```

I can get the properties from the property file. Is it possible to have a single variable to store these values based on configuration and access them in an optimised and readable way?

I tried using hash-map for every configuration separately and fetching it from that. But it is increasing my code redundancy as if I perform same steps for every configuration and if-elsed the configuration name to get the hashmap values.

Currently I am using the properties with hashmap like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> conf1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> conf2 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> conf3 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> conf4 = new HashMap<>();

conf1.put("UserName", prop.getProperty(“conf1.username"));
conf1.put("Password",prop.getProperty("conf1.password"));
conf1.put(“name”,prop.getProperty("conf1.name"));
conf1.put("context”,”conf1,context”);

conf2.put("UserName", prop.getProperty(“conf2.username"));
conf2.put("Password",prop.getProperty("conf2.password"));
conf2.put(“name”,prop.getProperty("conf2.name"));
conf2.put("context”,”conf2,context”);

conf3...
conf4...

if (Conf.equalsIgnoreCase(“conf1”)) {
    GenerateTestFile(
          "Name:“ + conf1.get("Name") + “-UserName:” +
          conf1.get("UserName") + “-Password:” + conf1.get("Password") + 
        "-Context:” + conf1.get(“Context”) ,FileName);
} else if (Conf.equalsIgnoreCase(“conf2”)) {
GenerateTestFile(
          "Name:“ + conf2.get("Name") + “-UserName:” +
          conf2.get("UserName") + “-Password:” + conf2.get("Password") + 
        "-Context:” + conf2.get(“Context”) ,FileName);
}
Else if(conf3){…}
Else if(conf4){…}
```

Comment: The question is not so clear. Please give more information: sample properties file content, and code snippets you use.

Comment: Try `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` where the key is the name of the configuration, and the value (`Map<String,String>`) is the configuration parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` where the key is the name of the configuration, and the value (`Map<String,String>`) is the configuration parameters.

To load the file, you would do something like this:

```
private static Pattern RE = Pattern.compile(
        "([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");

private static Map<String,Map<String,String>> loadConfs(String name)
        throws IOException {
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> confs = new HashMap<>();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try (InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream(name)) {
        props.load(in);
    }
    for (String propName: props.stringPropertyNames()) {
        Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(propName);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String confName = matcher.group(1);
            String parmName = matcher.group(2);
            Map<String,String> conf = confs.get(confName);
            if (conf == null) {
                conf = new HashMap<>();
                confs.put(confName, conf);
            }
            conf.put(parmName, props.getProperty(propName));
        }
    }
    return confs;
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> confs = loadConfs("conf.properties");
...
Map<String,String> conf = confs.get(confName);
if (conf != null) {
    GenerateTestFile(
            "Name:“ + conf.get("Name")
            + “-UserName:” + conf.get("UserName")
            + “-Password:” + conf.get("Password")
            + "-Context:” + conf.get(“Context”),
            FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> conf = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    String currentConfName = "conf" + i;
    HashMap<String, String> currentConf = new HashMap<>();
    currentConf.put("UserName", prop.getProperty(currentConfName + ".username"));
    //And everythin else you want to add

    conf.put(currentConfName, currentConf);
}
```

Equally you can then generate your files by iterating over the HashMap